# Using openpyxl how can i set my colorscale row by row without setting upper and lower value

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

As the question says I'd like to apply a colour scale conditional format row by row.

Can I set this up without setting the high and low values as my data is always different when the report is ran.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, but it's best to look at the source of an existing file to work out how to do this.

Comment: @CharlieClark are you able to elaborate? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the start_type, mid_type and end_type as 'num'
If you use percentile it works like a charm.
Using the below controls, i can just set a range and the code does the rest

```
    color_scale_rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type="percentile",
                              start_value=0,
                              start_color=colors.RED,
                              mid_type="percentile",
                              mid_value=50,
                              mid_color=colors.YELLOW,
                              end_type="percentile",
                              end_value=100,
                              end_color=colors.GREEN)
```